# Jhipster dockerized application fails behind a reverse proxy

Tags: spring-boot, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, jhipster

I run my nginx reverse proxy in a server over ssl with the domain: `mydomain.com`.
This is below the nginx config:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    upstream myApp {
        server my-app:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    server{
        listen 443 ssl;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3 TLSv1.1;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/myapp_chain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/private.pem;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr; # To forward the original client's IP address 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; # to forward the  original protocol (HTTP or HTTPS)
        proxy_set_header Host $host; # to forward the original host requested by the client
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;


        location / {
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /portal {
            proxy_pass http://myApp/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

When I work locally, the app works well. And when I run it also with a different port (but not behind nginx) it is accessible well.

The issue is when I access it with `mydomain.com/portal`, I get this error (in picture). I allowed **CORS** btw.

And the console in the browser shows:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
There are two places we should make changes to take into consideration the /portal sub-path.

At the index.html in the Angular project (webapps in case of JHipster)

```
<base href="/portal/" />
```

And in the nginx configuration file, we should add this line:

```
rewrite ^/portal(/.*)$ $1 break;
```

to remove the `"/portal"` prefix from the request URI before forwarding the request to the myApp service.